# Crashlytics Android Studio plugin fails to initialize

Tags: android-studio, crashlytics

I'm running Android Studio 0.5.1. I've downloaded the Crashlytics Android Studio plugin and installed it from the disc. When I restart Android Studio, I get the following exception

```
Plugin 'com.crashlytics.tools.androidstudio' failed to initialize and will be disabled.  Please restart Android Studio.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:471)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:189)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:185)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:161)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClassInsideSelf(PluginClassLoader.java:124)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.tryLoadingClass(PluginClassLoader.java:77)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.OSGiPluginServices.createOSGi(OSGiPluginServices.java:62)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.CrashlyticsPlugin.initComponent(CrashlyticsPlugin.java:89)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:548)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:225)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:199)
    at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.getComponentInstance(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:371)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:89)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:508)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:150)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:46)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator PluginClassLoader[com.crashlytics.tools.androidstudio, 1.5.0]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 44 more
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Hemal from Crashlytics here! Can you go ahead and try to install the plugin.zip file instead of the jar and let me know if that works?

Comment: That seems to have done it. I was downloading with Safari at first, and the file was getting automatically unzipped. Your note prompted me to try downloading with Chrome, which preserved the zip. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Hemal Shah, I'm facing same issues, but didn't work using the zip file. IntelliJ13 + Crashlytics, same stacktrace as joates.

Comment: Thanks, faced the same issue but the plugin installation of the ZIP file instead of JAR fixed the issue.

Comment: I tried both Android Studio and Intellij zip plugin. I'm using Android Studio 0.5.8 and I'm having this error: http://pastebin.com/1SaYD9Gy

Comment: Hemal. You are amazing.

Comment: Where can I find the zip file?

Comment: What happen if i dont what add the plugin, i need fix this issue with the jar.

Comment: @Hemal Shah where can I find the .zip file? I googled it but I did not find something. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

Use **Fabric Tool**.You don't need to write any code.Check out the below **steps** to install `Crashlytics` in your application.

1. Get in to this [Fabric link](https://fabric.io/onboard) .Then sign
   up and login to your account.
2. In Android Studio, Click File -> settings->plugin-> In top search bar, search this `Fabric for Android` then click **browse**, you see the fabric android studio file.
3. Then download a **Fabric Android Studio
   Plugin.Zip** file.finally, restart Android Studio
4. Then you can see the Fabric icon in your eclipse tool.Check the
   below screenshot:

   [image]
5. Login fabric -> Enter Organization -> click install the crashlytics tool.It will add the Codes
   automatically.You don't need to write a single line of code.It will
   add codes in `manifest` file and `build.gradle`.
6. After it successfully installed,Run your application.If your
   application getting crash,it will be notified in your `fabric
   dashboard`.
7. **Output:**

   Below I am posted the crash report in dashboard:

   [image]

For further Reference: [Crashlytics](https://dev.twitter.com/crashlytics/crash-reporting)

Comment: It work fine in Lollipop but when run the app in kitkat  than app not run and find error is....   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers

Comment: For me,it is working in kitkat too @Destro Check is there any other error

Comment: yes @Naruto Fabric Tool is best tool  for android application (Crashlytics )just cast vote.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error "NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/SwingUtilities"

I had to download and use jdk1.7.0_65 instead of jdk1.8.0_05 and change the path in my environment variables.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

Oh gods, i thought it's not work, but it does! It now show icon in toolbar, but i assign hotkey on crashlytics and it pop up below(!) IDEA CE 13.1.4 screen.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For you guys using safari to download the plugin. Use some other browser that won automatically unzip the container.

Android studio requires you to install the zipped file, not the individual .jar:s

Edit:
Another option is to go to Safari -> Preferences and untick the auto-open option. 
Thanks @m vai

Comment: No need for it, just go Safari -> Preferences and untick the auto-open option.

Answer (score 0):

Select "Plugins" on the right of the Settings Dialog. Click "Install plugin from disk…" and choose the ***downloaded*** **zip** file. 
Do not unzip file. Choose ***downloaded*** **zip** file.

Comment: "Fail to load plugin descriptor from file CrashlyticsPlugin.zip" error