# Twitter Fabric failed to install after downloading plugin

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I try to follow the [download approach](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html) to configuring my android studio app with Fabric. I followed the instructions to go to `Preferences > Plugins > Install Plugin from Disk`. After I click OK, the system asked me to restart. When I restart I get the following error (as a picture). Any ideas how I might get this download approach to work?

[image]

Comment: Similar question try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464063/crashlytics-android-studio-plugin-fails-to-initialize

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric and Crashlytics here.

The other post mentioned should do the trick. It seems like the .zip was auto-extracted by your browser. Using the full .zip to install the plugin should work.

-Mike